# Cypher query Neo4J

Tags: neo4j

I am very new to Neo4j so need some assistance
I am trying to to execute following  query in NeO4j
The idea is extract all the users who used to post on ['collapse' ,'science' ,'politics']
subreddits before 01 Jan 2020 and are now posting on ['covid19','china_flu','coronavirus']
subreddits.
This syntax is not working
u.username IN {match (c:User)

Query

```
match (s:Subreddit)--(p:Post)--(u:User) 
where toLower(p.title) =~ '.*corona.*' 
and s.display_name IN ['covid19','china_flu','coronavirus']
and p.created_utc_str >= '2020-01-01'
and p.created_utc_str <= '2020-01-30'
and u.username IN {match (c:User)-[:Submitted]->(b:Post)-[:Submitted]->(t:Subreddit)
                    where t.display_name IN ['collapse' ,'science' ,'politics'] 
                    and p.created_utc_str < '2020-01-01'
                    return distinct c.username}
return distinct  s,p,u
order by p.created_utc_str
```

Any assistance will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think WHERE IN clauses only accept lists, not subqueries. I rewrote your query as this and it parses correctly on Neo4j 4.0.3

```
// Collect the distinct users who posted to pre-COVID subreddits into 'cspUsers'    
match (c:User)-[:Submitted]->(b:Post)-[:Submitted]->(t:Subreddit)
                    where t.display_name IN ['collapse' ,'science' ,'politics'] 
                    and b.created_utc_str < '2020-01-01'
with collect(distinct c.username) as cspUsers
// Match users who posted into COVID subreddits who are also in 'cspUsers'
match (s:Subreddit)--(p:Post)--(u:User) 
where toLower(p.title) =~ '.*corona.*' 
and s.display_name IN ['covid19','china_flu','coronavirus']
and p.created_utc_str >= '2020-01-01'
and p.created_utc_str <= '2020-01-30'
and u.username IN cspUsers
return distinct  s,p,u
order by p.created_utc_str
```